# Tab bar navigation bug in ios6 app

Tags: ios

A bug is affecting my ios6 iPhone app.

Using storyboards, the "top" view controller is a `tabbar` controller and several of the tabs are controlled with the navigation controller.

When the app first loads, you are at the top level of one of the navigation controllers.  You can navigate to the right just fine but "rewinding" to the left does not show the proper slide animation; instead, it appears with no sliding animation.  This affects all unwind segues on that navigation controller.

Once you select another tab and come back again, the problem with the animation fixes itself.  If you resume the app from the background, it also works fine.  The problem is only on the initial launch of the app.

Why is this and how does it get resolved?

Comment: Did you actually set up unwind segues? If so, you shouldn't be. The navigation back through the navigation controller's stack is controlled automatically by the navigation controller.

Comment: for the unwind segues i just dragged from the button in the nav bar to the exit icon ans selected the unwind segue.

The weird thing is that after you select a different tab, the problem goes away and the unwind segue animates fine.

Comment: What are these unwind segues doing? Are you going backwards in a chain of view controllers in a navigation controller?

Comment: yes exactly.  Its going back where the sliding animation fails.  Works fine going to the forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from your question, you're trying to use unwind segues to go backwards through the controllers embedded in a navigation controller. If that's what you're doing, it's wrong. You should delete those unwind segues. You don't need to add any segues or code to do this - the navigation controller takes care of this automatically.

**After Edit:**

After reviewing your project, the problem was with the custom tab bar controller. You left out calling [super viewDidAppearAnimated:animated] in the viewDidAppear method, and that caused this weird behavior. The reason it goes away after switching tabs, is because viewDidAppear for the tab bar controller is never called again -- only when the app first starts.

Comment: I think the unwind segues are setup correctly.  They work fine with the exception of the animation.  Only on the initial run until I select another tab

Comment: The point is, there shouldn't be any unwind segues. There is no bug, I think you're setting things up incorrectly, but since you really haven't fully described what you set up in the storyboard, I can't tell.

Comment: ok.  In the storyboard i have a chain of view controllers embedded in a nav controller.  The top view controller we can call A.  when the user taps a cell in the tableview of A, a push segue to view controller B is perfumed perfectly with the sliding animation.  I have a method in A called -(IBAction) doSomething:(UIStoryboardSegue *) sender.  In the B view controller, I dragged from a button to the exit symbol at the bottom and selected doSomething.

Comment: @user2018711, Yes, and when you tap the back button, it will go back to A with no unwind segue necessary.

Comment: Right.  I wired the back button to the exit segue.  When I press the back button it does segue back to A but without the sliding animation.  Thats what I cant figure out because this strange behavior only occurs upon initial launching

Comment: @user2018711, That's because you're not supposed to do that. The navigation controller automatically provides the actions for the back button. You should delete all unwind segues.

Comment: I want to run some code in the A viewcontroller when the unwind segue is performed.  Thats why I made the method -(IBAction) doSomething in the A viewcontroller.  If I delete the unwind segue and let the nag controller handle the unwind segue automatically, how do i run the code in A view controller?

Comment: @user2018711, first, this is NOT an unwind segue -- navigation controllers push (forward) and pop (backwards) controllers. Do you need to pass back some information from B to A?

Comment: yeah.  I want to run some code in A when the pop occurs.  Not really pass info but i want to run some code in A.  What I had been doing in -(IBAction) doSomething:(UIStoryboardSegue *) sender is getting the B viewcontroller from [sender sourceViewController].  Then I have access to B from A

Comment: @user2018711, That can be done in the ViewDidAppear method of A. You can use the method, isMovingToParentViewController, to test whether the the view is appearing because you pushed from one before it, or appeared because one was popped off it.

Comment: @user2018711, I think I've answered your question, so you should accept it. If you have other questions, you should post a new one.

Comment: OK i got rid of the unwind segue  and let the nav controller pop back to A but still getting the same problem.  It does pop back to A but without the "sliding" animation.

Comment: @user2018711, I have no idea how that can be happening -- I've never seen that. If you want to send me your app, I'll look at it and figure out what's wrong. Clearly,, you're doing something wrong. My email is rdelmar@comcast.net if you want to send.